# Ajax form submission results in empty POST array

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have spend so much time on trying to figure out why when I try to submit a basic form in an ajax request, the POST array is empty ? I have double and triple checked and it is simply not going through. Maybe I am missing something ?

I appreciate any advice!

HTML

```
<form id="csv_form" action="?" method="post" name="action" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="csv" class="csv" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload CSV" />
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$('#csv_form').submit(function(event){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "import.leads.ajax.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(html){
            alert(html);
         }
    });
});
```

import.leads.ajax.php

```
var_dump($_POST); //output array(0) { }
```

Comment: I think for a file you may have to use `FormData` if you're trying to send it via ajax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData -----> better still: http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is this the cause of the empty POST array ? Shouldn't it contain something, i.e Submit ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to verify, just include a regular form field with some data and confirm that it's data does reach the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use formData to upload a file via ajax. Try reading this simple article on how to upload a file using ajax, it's super simple!

http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax